# Extract fields from a JSON in Python(Django)

Tags: python, json, django

Hello I am new to the python world, and I am learning, I am currently developing a WebApp in Django and I am using ajax for sending requests, what happens is that in the view.py I get a JSON, from which I have not been able to extract the attributes individually to send to a SQL query, I have tried every possible way, I appreciate any help in advance.

```
def profesionales(request):
    body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
    received_json = json.loads(body_unicode)
    data = JsonResponse(received_json, safe=False)

    return data
```

**Data returns the following to me**

```
{opcion: 2, fecha_ini: "2021-02-01", fecha_fin: "2021-02-08", profesional: "168", sede: "Modulo 7", grafico: "2"}
```

This is the answer I get and I need to extract each of the values ​​of each key into a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can interpret this as dict.

```
for key in received_json:
   print(key,received_json[key])
   # do your stuff here
```

but if it's always a object with same keys (fixed keys), you can access directly:

```
key_data = received_json[key]
```